# Adding Link (FontAwesome) to head using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome, vwo

I'm working at a mid sized company as an a/b tester. That being said, I only have access to CSS and JS/Jquery through our testing software we use (VWO).

I'd like to link in FontAwesome to create some quick icons for one of the tests I want to run, but I don't know if it's possible.

I tried this approach:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">');

$('a').append('<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>');
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Am I totally off here? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Dalorzo, font is loaded from that cdn, so I don't think that's not a problem. I believe it's caused by how he adds the that piece of html to his anchors. I think it's done before the DOM is ready.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980072/how-to-load-and-external-css-file-from-the-cdn-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980072/how-to-load-and-external-css-file-from-the-cdn-with-javascript)