# How to load and external css file from the CDN with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cross-domain, xss

briefly, I want to load the bootstrap css file on a [web page](https://secure.helpscout.net/members/register/13/) on the internet (not on my website), to do some customization on it using Javascript in the browser console.

I tried to load bootstrap from the CDN using jQuery like this:

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' />");
```

When doing that I get this error message:

[image: error message]

What should I do to load it successfully to the page ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323631/how-to-override-content-security-policy-while-including-script-in-browser-js-con

Answer (score 2):

From js standpoint your approach is right. You tried to load a script from another site and, because you've restricted this by Content Security Policy (CSP), you can't. Check your CSP metatag.

I suggest you to read more about it [in this MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)

To simply allow all **just for test if error still appears**, you can use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280371/7732200) with detail explanation of how this tag works

BTW, this works for me:

```js
 function loadCss(filename) {
    var cssNode = document.createElement("link");
    cssNode.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    cssNode.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    cssNode.setAttribute("href", filename);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);
}

loadCss("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var mySheet = document.createElement('link');mySheet.type='text/css';mySheet.rel='stylesheet';mySheet.href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(mySheet);
```

Paste above code in DevTools -> console, hit Enter and you're good to go.

The main point here is to create HTML tag  at first, fill it up with properties and add it to the DOM's

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var head = document.head;
var link = document.createElement('link');



link.type = 'text/css';


link.rel = 'stylesheet';


link.href = fileName/url;



head.appendChild(link);
```